# if an object property is another object, how do i access that object-property's property or method in smarty?

Tags: php, templates, smarty, variable-assignment

```
class A
{
  public $property1;
  public $objB;

  public __construct(){
    $this->property1 = 'test';
    $this->objB = new B();
  }
}

class B
{
  public $title;
  public __construct(){
    $this->title = 'title1';
  }

}
```

so now i do this in the .php file

```
$a = new A();
```

in my .tpl i want to display $a->objB->title

how do i do that? i tried

```
$smarty->assign('a', $a);
```

i cannot do this in smarty

```
{$a->objB->title}
```

i also tried

```
$smarty->register_object('a', $a);
```

i cannot do this in smarty

```
{a->objB->title}
```

OR

```
{$a->objB->title}
```

Please advise.

Comment: Everytime i read these smarty posts, it's to me like "i'm trying to ride my bike up stairs to the 22nd floor, can anyone help". Well, how about "let the bike stand and walk"? Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think smarty supports that operation, I had the same problem and solved like this

```
{assign var='myObject' value=$a->objB}
{$myObject->title}
```

A little bit long and messy but still a solution.

Another solution might be assigning the title in the php side (but still the same long and messy code)

Or maybe you can define a smarty function that does it for you all the time you need,